# Where can I find Ansys Fluent for ubuntu?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am new to Ansys Fluent (the Ansys CFD product). Is it a windows-only software? 
My institute owns copies that work on windows only.
Online tutorials on how to install Fluent on ubuntu aren't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used on Linux systems but it's not free. So if your university only provides Windows versions, you will have to convince them to pay for Linux versions as well or buy it yourself.